# How to define Setup File Name at build time in InstallShield

Tags: installation, installshield

We are launching our installer build using IsCmdBld.exe and would like to define at buildtime the name of the Setup File Name .exe

I have tried doing this by passing a command similar to this:

```
IsCmdBld.exe -p c:\project_path\installer_project.ism -c "My Custom Configuration" -z "SetupFileName=My App 1.0"
```

Unfortunately, it seems SetupFileName is ignored.

Anybody got ideas?

Comment: Well, it's getting stored as a property in the .msi file, but that doesn't do what you're looking for. Try the automation layer (`ISWiProject` and friends).

Comment: Quick links: http://creativetechfix.blogspot.no/2015/04/installshield-automation-interface.html, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28615056/installshield-automation-cant-create-object

Answer (score 4):

This may not be the exact answer  you are looking for, but if you want to change the name within the project for each build, go to the Media / Releases menu.  Click on the project name under "Releases", and in the General information is the Setup File Name.  Enter your desired name here without the '.exe' extension.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Using Installshield for VS 2015 this is the updated answer:

[image]

Comment: Can we automatically append **application version** specified earlier in _Step 1: Organize Your Setup_ configuration process to this setup filename?

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would want your setup.exe to stay the same name every time you build. Especially the MSI filename. The version of the file can be set on the command line.

So for our setup, we specify the desired name of the setup.exe and msi filename in the product/release configuration of the ISM. Then on the command line, we always call the ISM with the same command line, which gives us repeatability/reliability.

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield\2012Spring SAB\System\IsCmdBld.exe" -p "E:\Path\to\the.ism" -y 3.6.356.2 -a "PRODUCT_CONFIGURATION" -o "E:\local\mergemodules"
>
> -y sets the version (ProductVersion) which also sets the resulting EXE version
>
> -a specifies the product configuration
>
> -o specifies a folder for merge modules (we limit the merge modules we consume)